# How to configure Internet Download Manager 6.11 with Wine?

Tags: 10.04, downloaders

I've been using IDM 5.01 Configured with on Wine on Backtrack 5 R3 (Ubuntu 10.04 lucid) [working fine].

Now I decided to change the version of IDM to 6.11 and when i add the URL and press download now the page that should come up, suddenly disappears and there's nothing I can do, can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/259228/alternative-to-internet-download-manager-6-x-x-for-ubuntu